# react-router-dom v6 NavLink is always active

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I followed Upgrading from v5 guide and I cannot get the NavLink component to work correctly.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrading-from-v5

v6 Navlinks:

```
    <NavLink
          className={(isActive) =>
            cx(isActive ? classes.linkActive : classes.link)
          }
          to="/seafarers"
          end
        >
          Seafarers
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          className={(isActive) =>
            cx(isActive ? classes.linkActive : classes.link)
          }
          end
          to="/"
        >
          Planning
        </NavLink>
```

Routes

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginScreen />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
        <Route path="forgot-password" element={<ForgotPasswordScreen />} />
        <Route path="seafarers" element={<SeafarersScreen />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Both "/" and "/seafarers" have active class

Note: NavLink elements are located in SeafarersScreen screen

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: The `NavLink` component API changed significantly in RRDv6, for example, the `isActive` is now a destructured property passed to a callback function on the props. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out I had to deconstruct the property of className as ternary operator always returned true for objects

```
    <NavLink
          className={({isActive}) => //(isActive) --> ({isActive})
            cx(isActive ? classes.linkActive : classes.link)
          }
          to="/seafarers"
          end
        >
          Seafarers
        </NavLink>
```

Comment: Also a follow up on this, if you have a problem of the link staying active at the website root always, then using the end prop will solve this issue. Something that I have faced.
If the end prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to render a link that is only active at the website root and not any other URLs, you can use:


`<NavLink to="/" end>
  Home
</NavLink>`

Answer (score 5):

Add **end** prop on parent route. This work for **react-router-dom: 6.4.4**.

```js
    <NavLink
        to="/"
        end
        className={({ isActive }) =>`nav-link ${isActive && 'active'}`}>
      Notes
    </NavLink>
```

From react-router documentation, here is the link: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link

Answer (score 2):

For **react-router-dom v6**

This example demonstrates how to make a custom `<Link>` component to render something different when the link is "active" using the `useMatch()` and `useResolvedPath()` hooks.

[Official doc for active link](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/custom-link?file=src/App.tsx)

Comment: There is no "exact" prop in v6 routes

Comment: use `activeClassName` in `NavLink` component

Comment: Again, there is no "activeClassName" prop in Navlink. There is in v5, but this is v6. They changed the way routes and navlinks work

Comment: Kindly follow the official documentation here https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/custom-link?file=src/App.tsx

Comment: Thank you for the docs. It will certainly be useful when I need more complex link styling, but I figured out the problem with their NavLink component. I had to deconstruct the property before using it: ({isActive})

Comment: This answer isn't helpful at all. OP isn't trying to make a custom link component.

Answer (score 1):

```
<NavLink
  to="/"
  style={({ isActive }) => ({ color: isActive ? "green" : "blue" })}
  className={yourClasses}
>
  Profile
</NavLink>
```